# A similar ServiceBus framework like nServiceBus?

Tags: servicebus

Is there a similar Service Bus framework like nServiceBus? 
What i want is a service bus that work inside an application other than distributed applications.
Components of the same application pub/sub messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Retlang](http://code.google.com/p/retlang/). It's a great library for message passing.

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked at [Mass Transit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/)?

Answer (score 1):

Newly released, Service Bus 1.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193022(v=azure.10).aspx